# Developer rejected State?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4, iostream

Got 2 versions of app in appstore 1.0 and 1.1 , But both are not live in the App Market. Now I had rejected the app for the version 1.1 which was in the developer release status. 
But since I have rejected it, i'm unable to find the the way to re-upload my new version to the appstore again.

I want to re-upload the binary, since I have rejected my previous version.

Answer (score 3):

In iTunes Connect, go to the page with details of your new version and click the "Ready to Upload Binary" button again. Note that you won't have the opportunity to edit your keywords after this.